# How do I query an XML variable in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I want to get the value of the QuestionID node (1000000), but all I get in return is just a blank output.

Can you please point me in the right direction?

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<QuestionaryAnswerList xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="schemas/src/system/antagelse/x20160401">
  <Answer>
    <QuestionId>1000000</QuestionId>
    <PossibleAnswerId>100000010</PossibleAnswerId>
    <AnswerValue>
      <Tekst>No</Tekst>
    </AnswerValue>
  </Answer>
  </QuestionaryAnswerList>';
 
  SELECT CAST(@xml.query('/QuestionaryAnswerList/Answer/PossibleAnswerId') AS VARCHAR(max))
```

Comment: You need to define your namespaces; specifically your default one (`schemas/src/system/antagelse/x20160401`). The fact the value is in a variable is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply : **respect** the XML namespace on your XML root node, and use the XQuery `.value()` function to get at the data:

```
-- establish the default XML namespace
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'schemas/src/system/antagelse/x20160401')
SELECT 
    @xml.value('(/QuestionaryAnswerList/Answer/QuestionId/text())[1]', 'varchar(20)')
```

Comment: Hello @marc_s, that worked. Thanks a ton for your help.  Can you please explain to me, why I have to reference only the third namespace and not the first two as well? Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @givnv: the first two are "standard" namespaces - plus they are defined with a **prefix** (`xsd` and `xsi`) which is never used in the XML document; the third is defined *without* a prefix, and thus is the **default namespace** that applies to all XML nodes (unless they're specifically marked with a prefix of another namespace).